# Java - Validating Empty Field

Tags: java, swing, junit

I'm trying to validate that a specific field is required (isbnTextField). I want to make sure I wrote a test first to follow the principles of agile development. However, I'm receiving a null pointer exception in my test `testThatBookNumberIsRequired`. Why isn't this textField being found?

**Edit:**

```
public class BookOrderingGUI extends JFrame {

    private JTextField isbnTextField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BookOrderingGUI window = new BookOrderingGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */

    public BookOrderingGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 584, 412);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel panelOrders = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Orders", null, panelOrders, null);
        panelOrders.setLayout(null);

        isbnTextField = new JTextField();
        isbnTextField.setBounds(80, 8, 86, 20);
        panelOrders.add(isbnTextField);
        isbnTextField.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public class TestBookOrdering extends TestCase {
    private BookOrderingGUI window;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.window = new BookOrderingGUI();
        this.window.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatBookNumberIsRequired() {
        JTextField target = (JTextField) this.window.getComponentAt(80, 8);
        target.setText(null);
        target.postActionEvent();
        assertFalse(target.getText().isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just make the text field package private and access it directly from the test. That is easier and less error prone. If that creates an issue later on (why would it?), you can always go for the complicated option.

Comment: So you're saying make ```target``` private similar to how I've got ```window```? I'm still getting a null pointer exception. @assylias

Comment: I've added some more code @assylias I think this might be dealing with the Pane's the field is stored in.

Comment: What I meant is: (i) in `BookOrderingGUI` make the field package private (i.e. remove private and simply use: `JTextField isbnTextField;`) and (ii) in your test, simply use `JTextField target = window.isbnTextField;`.

Comment: Okay, I've made that change but I'm still getting that exception. @assylias

Comment: If you need a variable from a class then create a "getter" method. Don't try to access the variable directly. The real question is why is the `testThatBookNumberIsRequired()` part of the TestBookOrdering class and not part of the BookOrderingGUI class where it is defined?

Comment: Separation of concerns. The actual GUI itself should only contain features and/or expected functionality. The tests should reflect what the GUI does. I wrote a test first that I knew would fail so I could then write production code to make it pass. In this case, a method that validates when the field is blank. @camickr

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested I ended up writing a getter method to target a specific field and button. Being that an action was tied to this button, I then simulated the user clicking by using `doClick()`. I also made an inital flag to determine the state of when the field became invalid. The result came out like so:

```
@Test
public void testThatBookNumberIsRequired() {
    targetField = this.window.getBookNumber();
    targetButton = this.window.getSubmit();

    targetField.setText(null);
    targetButton.doClick();

    assertFalse(this.window.isValid);
}
```

Comment: Having to see a JOptionPane show up when the validation runs is quite annoying, haha. If anyone knows a way to prevent this during testing please let me know :-)